# Setup Visual Studio Code to transpile typescript on build and debug

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm a long time (15+ years) Visual Studio user and am excited to learn both Typescript and the new leaner, meaner Visual Studio Code. I've been trying to setup VSCode like VS, where when you hit F5 it transpiles to Javascript and launches the debugger.

I've found posts that trigger it on save, or using another shortcut (run via tasks.json) - but I'm really surprised there isn't a way of doing this on such a fundamental command, unless I'm really missing something embarrassingly obvious.

At this point I'm just trying to use the ["Hello World" greeter sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html) checked out directly from Microsoft, where it has a manual step of `tsc --sourcemap greeter.ts`. I just want that to happen automatically, like it does in VS, on any files that need transpiling before I start to run / debug.

Does anyone know how to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So, using help from responses here was the path of least resistance. After opening vscode, I:

1. File -> Open Folder
2. Created an empty sub-folder within my code directory called HelloWorld in this case
3. Created a **tsconfig.json** file and copied the example from [this article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) which is:

   ```
   {
       "compilerOptions": {
           "target": "es5",
           "module": "commonjs",
           "sourceMap": true
       }
   }
   ```
4. Created a **helloWorld.ts** as directed by the same article, which is:

   ```
   class Startup {
   public static main(): number {
       console.log('Hello World');
       return 0;
       }
   }
   Startup.main();
   ```
5. Hit F5 (to Debug) and VSCode asked me if I wanted a Node.js environment or a VSCode environment, I selected **Node.js**.
6. It generated me a **launch.json**, where I did the following edits:
7. Switched *"program": "${workspaceRoot}/app.js",* to *"program": "${workspaceRoot}/**helloWorld.js**",*
8. Replaced the null in preLaunchTask to: *"preLaunchTask": "**tsc**",*
9. Replaced the 3 instances of *sourceMaps* from false to ***true***.
10. Hit F5 again, VSCode pops up an info saying no task runner configured. I click configure and select **TypeScript - Watch Mode**.
11. Put a breakpoint on a line in my ts file
12. Hit F5 one last time and everything works!

So tsc compiler seems pretty slow, takes about 4-5 seconds to transpile on my 2 year old Win10 computer. I see the benefit of TypeScript - Watch Mode so it could it's transpiling as you hit Save. Otherwise, if you transpile everytime before you debug, it doesn't seem to detect whether it needs a transpile or not, so this is the ideal scenario that matches what Visual Studio developers are used to.

Answer (score 5):

Essentially VS Code allows you to create tasks to automate development processes (cleaning files/folders, compiling, bundling, etc.) and also allows you to create environment configurations to run your project.

To have them work together the environment configuration allows specification of a *preLaunchTask* which will run the defined task before debugging. To create a workflow similar to Visual Studio you could create a compile task and run the task before the debugger by setting it as the *preLaunchTask*.

- [This article](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) walks through the process of getting started with TypeScript for both [express](http://expressjs.com/) (web) and [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) apps.

**Example running *tsc* (TypeScript compiler) before debugging**

1.**Create a [tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file in the root of your project with your choice of compile options.**

Example [tsconfig.json](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) file (You may need to change the *module* setting to best suit your project. *amd* is typically a web project, *commonjs* is typically a [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) project but everyone's preference varies:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es6",
        "module": "amd",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules",
        "bower_components",
        "jspm_packages",
        "tmp",
        "temp"
    ]
}
```

2.**Create a *launch.json* file to [run and debug your project](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging) and set the *preLaunchTask* to *tsc*.**

The easiest way to do this is simply hit *F5*. The first time you run it will ask to "Select an environment", if you have already created a launch.json file and would like to start fresh, delete the file. For TypeScript I normally choose [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/) which will allow you to run in process or within a web context with frameworks such as [express](http://expressjs.com/).

Example *launch.json* file (this example is of an [express](http://expressjs.com/) app):

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Launch",
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/www",
            "stopOnEntry": false,
            "args": [],
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc",
            "runtimeExecutable": null,
            "runtimeArgs": [
                "--nolazy"
            ],
            "env": {
                "NODE_ENV": "development"
            },
            "console": "internalConsole",
            "sourceMaps": false,
            "outDir": null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: So I didn't quite use your exact config files, but followed the documentation plus some of @Burt_Harris suggestions to be able to answer my own question.

Comment: Excellent, glad you were able to get setup. It took me some time to get use to Visual Studio Code but now that I have it's my default IDE for anything outside the .NET stack (haven't attempted to start compiling C# within VS Code).

Answer (score 3):

The short answer (in a new project directory) is:

- Press **Ctrl+Shift+B** to Build your project in VSCode
- If `.vscode/tasks.json` is not already configured, a message will give you the option to **Configure Task Runner**, press that button.
- Choose one of the two predefined TypeScript options.
- You can close the `tasks.json` window this opened up.

After having tried both TypeScript options, I prefer the *... in watch mode* option.   That way, after starting the background process with **Ctrl+Shift+B** once, incremental transpiles happen whenever a file is saved, making launching the program for debugging that much faster...

For more details, follow this link: http://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript#_transpiling-typescript-into-javascript

If you want to generate a source map (a good idea), you need to setup `tsconfig.json`.  The quick way to do that from VSCode is:

- Press **Ctrl+Shift+C** to open up a command line window.
- type the command `tsc --init --sourceMap` to set up a template `tsconfig.json`
- type the command `exit`

Finally, if you want to *use* the source map while debugging, you need to generate and edit the `.vscode/launch.json` file.   The quick way to do that is:

- If `.vscode/launch.json` doesn't already exist, pressing **F5** will prompt you to choose and environment.   Choose *Node.js*.
- Edit the generated file replacing all occurances of `"sourceMaps": false` with `"sourceMaps": true`.

I'm not sure why the defaults omit source maps, it currently seems like one of the most common bumps in the road for people starting to use VSCode + TypeScript.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid hitting any key, except for F5

Comment: I believe that once you've done the steps above, F5 will do what you want.